# What value can a variable take, and is it limited by a function's domain?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

If we define a variable $x$ how do we talk about what values it can take, is it contextual? Can a variable take discrete values if we choose? How do we define this, or is it just that we understand we are only interested in a certain quantity at a certain set of values? If we define a function $f$ on $x$ and $x$ can vary outside of the domain does this mean that $f(x)$ is simply not defined for these values or does $x$ not have the ability to vary outside of this? What would be the value of $f(x)$ for $x$ outside the domain of $f$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, at the end of the day, it depends on the context. Someone might simply write $f(x) = x^2$, for instance, and without further context it is understood that the domain is all of $\mathbb R$. This is just based on the convention that $x$ is typically used for real numbers. By contrast, if someone wrote $f(z) = z^2$, it would be natural to assume that the domain is $\mathbb C$, and for $f(n) = n^2$, one would assume that $n \in \mathbb N$. All of these are simply conventions that have been adopted over the years.

Note that strictly speaking, the domain of a function is **part of its definition.** So discussing $f(x)$ for $x$ not in the domain of $f$ is nonsense. It doesn't mean anything in particular. For instance, let's say I introduce the function

$$ f(n) = \left ( \frac{n}{2} \right )! $$

I would likely clarify that here $f$ is defined for even integers $n \geq 0$. If someone else then came along and wrote down $f(3/5)$, you should ask what they mean as $3/5$ is not in $f$'s domain.

Comment: but I could have in whatever context, having n change perhaps if I have a function $g$ and $g(n)$ which is defined for all $n$? And define values of $g(n)$

Comment: Yes, it's totally up to you to decide what domain your functions have.